# C++/CX - Case insensitive comparison of two String objects

Tags: string, comparison, c++-cx

I have two String^ objects and i'd like to do a case-insensitive comparision for equality. That is "blah" should be considered equal to "BLAH". I know that String::CompareOrdinal is available to me, but that is case-sensitive. Is there a simple case-insensitive solution?

Disclaimer :) - I know that String^ is not a full-featured string class and it's recommended not to use it for general string operations...but in this specific situation I would actually prefer to keep the objects as String^ type. So there is the challenge, can you achieve this with String^'s ? :)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`_wcsicmp` or `_wcsicmp_l`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k59z8dwe.aspx).  For example, given two non-null `Platform::String`s, `r` and `s`:

```
_wcsicmp(r->Data(), s->Data());
```